# Xamarin.IOS tableview custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm working on a project and I'm pretty much stuck right now.

I am trying to create a custom cell for my tableview which I programmily generated.

However I got no clue on how to change the cell height from my code.

Would really appriciate some answers or different ways to do it

Here is some code to look at:

View:
http://pastebin.com/WZFvLpZi

CustomCell.cs:
http://pastebin.com/vc2ZntLK

TableItem.cs:
http://pastebin.com/fjSWPi8u

TableSource.cs:
http://pastebin.com/1xhBtdGy

Comment: Please do not post links to code on external sites.  Take the time to extract the **relevant** portions of your code and post them inline with proper formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your TableSource override this method

```
public override float GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
```

Comment: or you can just say tableView.RowHeight = 120; However when overiding your method it will also override that property.